# List all students with pass or fail

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, case

I have table structure like this

**Student**

| Id | Student name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | AAAA |
| 2 | BBBB |

**Subject**

| Id | Subject name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Subject1 |
| 2 | Subject2 |

**Marks**

| student_id | subject_id | marks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 35 |
| 1 | 2 | 34 |
| 2 | 1 | 54 |
| 2 | 2 | 42 |

Requirement is like, list all students with Pass (>=35 marks in all subject) or Fail (<35 marks in any subject) status. Any suggestion ?

Not sure what to add to if condition

```
select student.id, student.name, 'status (if marks.marks >= 35, Pass, Fail)'
from student
inner join marks on marks.student_id = student.id
```

Expected output

| student_id | student_name | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAAA | Fail |
| 2 | BBBB | Pass |

Comment: join student and marks table then do query for marks < 35?

Comment: This seems like a Homework question, so please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions first and adapt your question accordingly. Especially for homework questions you are expected to show at least some effort in solving the problem yourself ...

Comment: It would help your question if you post an expected result. And it will help your question if you showed what you already tried ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join `Student` to `Marks` and group by student.
Then use a `CASE` expression that checks the min marks of each student to get the status:

```
SELECT s.id student_id, s.student_name, 
       CASE WHEN MIN(m.marks) >= 35 THEN 'Pass' ELSE 'Fail' END status
FROM Student s INNER JOIN Marks m
ON m.student_id = s.id
GROUP BY s.id;
```

I assume that `id` is the primary key of the table `Student`.
If not, change the `GROUP BY` clause to:

```
GROUP BY s.id, s.student_name
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c0701f74733933f924a867c23baadf79)

Comment: I missed the group by & aggregation part